# Active-record-import on_duplicate_key_update SUM existing value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, on-duplicate-key, activerecord-import

How is possible to SUM the value of array to my existing row field during on_duplicate_key_update?

For example:
Model.import array, on_duplicate_key_update: [ :column_value + array_value]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/#duplicate-key-update) of [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/)

This works on MySQL

```
Book.import [book], on_duplicate_key_update: "quantity = quantity + VALUES(quantity)"
```

Change the format accordingly for PostgreSQL

```
Book.import [book], on_duplicate_key_update: {
  conflict_target: [:id], columns: "quantity = books.quantity + excluded.quantity"
}
```